# HBase-0.90.6 configure in Window 7 error in hbase-site xml file

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have install **java 1.6 and hadoop-1.0.3** successfully. Now i want to configure **HBase-0.90.6 with hadoop** in window 7.According to [hbase document](http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html) i have to change in **hbase-env.sh** but **hbase-site.xml** create problem.

**Edit in hbase-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
```

**when open xml file in browser it shows**

[image]

so please suggest how to remove this problem? how to provide path ?

Comment: You should provide relative path rather than virtual path.

Answer (score 0):

I think at least it worth to recheck [this chapter](http://hbase.apache.org/book/config.files.html#hbase_default_configurations) of [HBase reference guide](http://hbase.apache.org/book/book.html), especially sub-chapter 2.3.4 recommendation related to CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks for your rply, my problem is solve . The xml is look like this :
<property>  
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>  
  <value>file:///C:/cygwin/usr/local/hbase/tmp/hbase/data</value>  
  <description>The directory shared by region servers.</description>  
</property>   

<property>
   <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name>
   <value>60010</value>
   <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.</description>
</property>